# Ошибка при запуске py файла из cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, python-3.6

Прописываю  `python3 Backup.py` в cmd, конмандная строка в нужной директории, открыто от имени Админа, вчера все работало

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Backup.py", line 25, in <module>
        shutil.make_archive(
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\shutil.py", line 1045, in make_archive
        filename = func(base_name, base_dir, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\shutil.py", line 942, in _make_zipfile
        zf.write(path, path)
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\zipfile.py", line 1776, in write
        shutil.copyfileobj(src, dest, 1024*8)
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\shutil.py", line 202, in copyfileobj
        buf = fsrc_read(length)
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: И тем не менее что-то с правами доступа. В принципе, может быть и такое, что антивирус проверяет в этот момент, что у вас там в архиве и не даёт с ним работать.

Comment: А вы случайно никак не занимаете этот архив или файлы, добавляемые в него?

Comment: Он создает новые архивы копирую файл, так что я никак не могу их использовать